# slurm ignores dependency on running job

Tags: cluster-computing, slurm, hpc

Suppose that on a cluster with slurm the job with ID 12345 is currently running. I want to submit another job that will start after this job finishes. I tried `sbatch -d after:12345 job.script`, but I noticed that `scontrol show job 12346` displays `Dependency=(null)`. I therefore tried `scontrol update JobId=12346 dependency=after:12345`, but `scontrol` still shows `Dependency=(null)`. Why is this dependency ignored? Can I change anything to make this work as desired? I don't see this problem if the dependency is a job that is not running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `-d after:12345`, you are setting a dependency on the start of job `12345`. As that job is currently running, the dependency is void in practice.

What you want is either

- `-d afterok:12345` to set a dependency on the successful completion of job `12345`; or
- `-d afterany:12345` to set a dependency on the end (successful, canceled, or failed) of job `12345`

Comment: Thanks this explains it. If anyone needs more information, see `man sbatch`.